# How can I count the number of elements with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main div in my page with a specific `id`. Now some input elements of the same class are present in this `div`. So how can I count the number of these elements of same class in this `div` using *jQuery*?

Comment: On what event? DOM-ready, on load, on click..?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

With `jQuery` you can use

```
$('#main-div .specific-class').length
```

otherwise in *Vanilla*JS (from `IE8` included) you may use

```
document.querySelectorAll('#main-div .specific-class').length;
```

Comment: With plain JS and in compliant/modern browsers you could use `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: My point was made after you mentioned it, and was really a caution that qSA() is only available in recent browsers.

Comment: Can someone show me how to use the jQuery example with a variable? I tried a couple things but haven't gotten it to work yet. I thought it would be like `console.log($(container_variable '.remove_element').length);`

Comment: Firgured it out:  `console.log($('#'+container_variable+' .remove_element').length);`

Comment: After 5 years your answer save my time. Thanks mate

Answer (score 23):

`document.getElementsByClassName("classstringhere").length`

The `document.getElementsByClassName("classstringhere")` method returns an array of all the elements with that class name, so `.length` gives you the amount of them.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question. Why is this not #1?

Comment: @user959690 Because OP wants to query by both ID and class. Moreover, the top answer is important because if you're dealing with IDs, `getElementById("someId").length` dosn't work and will only return `undefined`.

Answer (score 16):

You can get to the parent node and then query all the nodes with the class that is being searched. then we get the size

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parentId");
var nodesSameClass = parent.getElementsByClassName("test");
console.log(nodesSameClass.length);
```

```html
<div id="parentId">
  <p class="prueba">hello word1</p>
  <p class="test">hello word2</p>
  <p class="test">hello word3</p>
  <p class="test">hello word4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you sum all of the values so you'll get 9 as the result?

Comment: @Ducky why 9 if only exist 3 elements

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean listing 3 items, I'm talking about adding up the values, 2+3+4=9

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#maindivid').find('input .inputclass').length
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to write **explicitly** two methods which allow accomplishing this in ***pure JavaScript***:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('realClasssName').length
```

*Note 1:* Argument of this method needs a **string with the real class name, without the dot at the begin** of this string.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.realClasssName').length
```

*Note 2:* Argument of this method needs a **string with the real class name but with the dot at the begin of this string**.

*Note 3:* This method **works also with any other *CSS* selectors, not only with class selector**. So **it's more universal**.

---

I also write **one method, but using two name conventions** to solve this problem using ***jQuery***:

```
jQuery('.realClasssName').length
```

or

```
$('.realClasssName').length
```

*Note 4:* Here we also have to **remember about the dot, before the class name**, and **we can also use other *CSS* selectors**.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest example:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "count: " + document.querySelectorAll('.test').length;
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <ul>
      <li class="test">Coffee</li>
      <li class="test">Milk</li>
      <li class="test">Soda</li>
    </ul>

 </body> 
 </html>
```