# count of nodes selected for an xpath in chrome console

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, google-chrome-devtools

How to get count of nodes selected for an xpath in chrome console?

I was able to select a set of node with Xpath :

```
$x("//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer']")
```

in chrome console. but unable to get the count of number of nodes selected using count function in chrome using

```
$x(count("//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer']"))
```

while it is working fine in firefox using count function as

```
(//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer'])
```

Please help me to get count using chrome console

Comment: [count the number of element of same class in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681601/count-the-number-of-element-of-same-class-in-a-div)

Comment: `$x("//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer']").length`

Comment: Note: `$x("//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer']").length` only matches `rel` attributes that are exactly `noopener noreferrer`. In other words, it wouldn't match `noreferrer noopener`. I think `$x("//*[contains(@rel, 'noreferrer') and contains(@rel, 'noopener')]").length` is more thorough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can actually use xPath to tell you directly that count =)

```
count(locator)
```

for example

`count(//*)` -count all elements on the page - `$x("count(//*)")`

`count(//a)` - count all a attributes on the page - `$x("count(//a)")`

using console $x:

```
$x("//a").length
```

Actually your locator is almost correct

error -  `$x(count("//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer']"))`

the problem is that `count()` is a part of xPath, not a js function, so it should be located inside quotes:

fixed - `$x("count(//*[@rel='noopener noreferrer'])")`

Comment: Vitaliy Moskalyuk and Kayce Basques both for your answers. Both the suggestions are working now for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
$x("//*[contains(@rel, 'noreferrer') and contains(@rel, 'noopener')]").length
```

`$x()` returns an array of nodes that match the XPath selector, so we just use the native `length` property of the array to get the count.

The selector `contains(@rel, 'noreferrer') and contains(@rel, 'noopener')` ensures that your query isn't order-sensitive.