# How to exclude <a> From Javascript OnClick function so that the Link itself Works?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a function that borders a product anytime a user clicks on it (for a comparison feature). Currently anytime they click on anything within the box, it highlights, this is good. However, I want to exclude just the title which is also the link under the book so that when they click on the title(link) they are taken to another page.

Also, how can I limit the function to just 3 clicks? Currently they can highlight any number of books they want.

HTML Generated Code for Product:

```
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19''>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https://edubookenhancement.com/book/148927379x'> Book 19 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post html generated in browser for `product` , so that it would be easy to understand.

Comment: @Swati I have added the code!

Comment: In future please add enough code to replicate the issue, you have not provided any of your JavaScript.  Also only ask one question per question, you have two here: how to not have an event handler on the `a` tag and how to ensure there are only three items selected. They are two very different an unrelated questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below :

```js
//for counting clicks
var count = 0;

$(".product").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


  //if class is already there
  if ($(this).closest('.product').hasClass("compare")) {

    $(this).closest('.product').removeClass("compare");
    //decrement count

    count = count - 1;


  } else if (count <= 2) {
  //increment
    count += 1;
    $(this).closest('.product').toggleClass('compare');

  } else {
    //cannot select
    alert("cannot select more then 3 product");
  }


});
//getting current a click and redirect to page  specified in href   
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.product').toggleClass('compare1');
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  console.log(href);
  //redirect to that url
  window.location.href = href;


});
```

```css
img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.compare {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.compare1 {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19' '>
    <center>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.iarch.co.in/book/img/book.png" >
    </center>
    <div class="text" style="text-align: center;">
      <center>
        <a href="https://edubookenhancement.com/book/148927379x"> Book 19 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product" data-id="18" data-title="Book 18">
    <center>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.iarch.co.in/book/img/book.png" style="margin-top: 5%;">
    </center>
    <div class="text" style="text-align: center;">
      <center>
        <a href="https://edubookenhancement.com/book/148927379x"> Book 18 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product" data-id="18" data-title="Book 18">
    <center>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.iarch.co.in/book/img/book.png" style="margin-top: 5%;">
    </center>
    <div class="text" style="text-align: center;">
      <center>
        <a href="https://edubookenhancement.com/book/148927379x"> Book 18 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="product" data-id="18" data-title="Book 18">
    <center>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.iarch.co.in/book/img/book.png" style="margin-top: 5%;">
    </center>
    <div class="text" style="text-align: center;">
      <center>
        <a href="https://edubookenhancement.com/book/148927379x"> Book 17 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's perfect thanks! Is there also any way to not highlight the box when the <a> is clicked?

Comment: Actually this also does not allow me to remove a book by clicking on it again, it is registered as "selected". Previously I was able to select a book, then click again to unselect. Whereas here, if it registers it as a "selection" so on the 3rd click the alert shows up

Comment: Remove the count and if and else statements and just leave the toggle class. Then add a check to see how many elements have the class name compare and move the toggle inside the if statement of being less than 4 classes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681601/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-with-same-class)

Comment: @vonajots sorry, now check i didn't noticed  that before.

Comment: No worries, I've posted an answer just to make it easier for the person asking the question. @Swati

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite of Swati's answer to make sure you're not triggering the error in false instances.

```
$selectedItems = $('.compare').length;
if ($selectedItems < 4) {
    $(".product").on('click', function(e) {

      //IE Friendly Prevent Default
      if(typeof e.preventDefault == 'function'){
          e.preventDefault();
      } else {
          e.returnValue = false;
      }

      $(this).closest('.product').toggleClass('compare');
    }
} else {
    alert("Cannot select more then 3 product");
}
```

This method will count how many elements have the compare class and unless there is less than 4 you cannot trigger the compare functionality.

**Just as a warning using `e.preventDefault()` will cause your scripts not to run in IE. Ensure you implement IE fall backs for this function.**

Answer (score 0):

You should inspect the event that triggered the click. If the target is not an `a` tag do you logic, otherwise let the link do it's own work.

**Vanilla Javascript below**

```js
var products = document.querySelectorAll(".product");

for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //If the item clicked is an A tag, do nothing .. let the link do it's stuff
    if(event.target.tagName !== "A"){  
      //Check number of elements with the selectd class
      if(document.querySelectorAll(".product.selected").length <= 2 || this.classList.contains("selected")){ 
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".product.selected").length);
        this.classList.toggle("selected");    
        return false;
      }else{
        alert("Only 3 products can be selected for comparison")
      }
    }    
  })
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 19 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 20 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 21</a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 21 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery Version:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".product").on("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName !== "A") {
      console.log($(".product.selected").length) 
      if ($(".product.selected").length <= 2 || $(this).is(".selected")) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        return false;
      } else {
        alert("Only 3 products can be selected for comparison");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 19 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 20 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 21</a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='product' data-id='19' data-title='Book 19'>
    <center>
      <img class='img-responsive' src='admin_area/product_images/book-19.jpg' style='margin-top: 5%;'>
    </center>
    <div class='text' style='text-align: center;'>
      <center>
        <a href='https:www.google.com'> Book 21 </a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exclude an element to pointer events you can add this in your CSS

```
pointerEvents: none
```

If you want to limit the amount of clicks on an element:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgYZwz

Comment: pointer-events being set to none in the CSS basically disbales the function. You cannot click on a product to highlight it anymore and the link still does not work.

Comment: You need to add pointerEvents none to the element which need to avoid the click, not on the entire one, in this case <a style="{pointerEvents: none}"></a>

Comment: This just makes the link not clickable.