# how to count items in todolist app in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi how to update the count of to do items

```
<span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>

function updateCount() {
const count = list.childElementCount;

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use innerHTML, innerText or textContent;

```
var counter = document.querySelector("#item-count");    
counter.innerHTML = 0;
```

or

```
var counter = document.querySelector("#item-count");
counter.innerText = 0;
```

or

```
var counter = document.querySelector("#item-count");
counter.textContent = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main-div .specific-class').length
```

source: [How can I count the number of elements with same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681601/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-with-same-class)