# How can I use JavaScript to count the number of occurrences of a div class, and print the number to screen without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have a page that contains many div elements with the same class. All I want is a bit of JS to count them and print the total to the screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the number of elements with same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681601/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-with-same-class)

Comment: For clarity, I want to count the number of classes, not all div elements, such as:
`<div class="Special"></div>`

Comment: @SergeyGubarev Thanks, but no. That page comes up all the time in my searches, but I'm looking to solve this without jQuery.

Comment: second answer is without jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Count: " + document.querySelectorAll('.test').length;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<div class="test">Coffee</div>
<div class="test">Milk</div>
<div class="test">Soda</div>
```

Comment: This works great! Took me awhile to figure out that the script needs to be at the bottom of the page, but once there, it works perfectly! Thank you for answering so quickly, and for such clean code.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')

console.log(divs.length)
```

```html
<div>item 1</div>
<div>item 2</div>
<div>item 3</div>
```

See

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)