# How to count DIV with specific classes

Tags: jquery

I want to count the DIVs with specific class names and then add the number in H2 tag

Desired outcome

```
<h2 id="result">5 Cards found</h2>

<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
```

Comment: That's a topic for any jQuery tutorial -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) -> [How can I count the number of elements with same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681601/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-elements-with-same-class), [Count elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706106/count-elements-with-jquery), [jQuery counting elements by class - what is the best way to implement this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727303/jquery-counting-elements-by-class-what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this)

Comment: Well I found these but did not know how to add into h2 or a div. All those results printed to console.

Comment: Which is just another point for a jQuery tutorial, or the above mentioned Learning Center, or ... - but not SO (even though you will definitely find questions for that exact topic)

Comment: Or you add what you do know to the question so we people don't waste time on the parts you already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your live example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#result').html($('.post_card').length + " Cards found");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="result">5 Cards found</h2>

<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#result .count').html($('.post_card').length)
```

I've added a span yo your html as a container for the counted value, then we don't have to include the text `Cards found` in the return.

**Demo**

```js
$('#result .count').html($('.post_card').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="result"><span class="count"></span> Cards found</h2>

<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
<div class="post_card"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can like this, using the `length`.

```js
var count_post = $(".container .post_card").length;
var count_post_no = $(".container .no_post_card").length;

$('#result').append(count_post);
$('#result2').append(count_post_no);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post_card"></div>
  <div class="post_card"></div>
  <div class="post_card"></div>
  <div class="post_card"></div>
  <div class="post_card"></div>
  <div class="no_post_card"></div>
  <div class="no_post_card"></div>
  <div class="no_post_card"></div>
</div>

<h2 id="result">Result (post_card): </h2>
<br>
<h2 id="result2">Result (no_post_card): </h2>
```